# Jackson Deserialization aborts when sub-property has trailing null value

Tags: java, json, serialization, null, jackson

When sending out a JSON to be deserialized by Jackson it seems that if the last value of a subelement is `null`, Jackson will abort the deserialization.

---

**Bad:**

If I send this JSON to my receiver (below), the mapped `Content` object will be `null`, because the deserialization stops at `image`:

```
{"user":{"id":"1", "token":"ABC", "image":null},"content":{"id":"2"}}
```

**Good:**

If I send it like this, `image` will still have the `null` value as desired but the `Content` object will be created with its id:

```
{"user":{"id":"1", "image":null, "token":"ABC"},"content":{"id":"2"}}
```

This looks like a bug to me..?!

---

**simple Receiver**:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
public Response create(UserContent source) {
        UserContent dbResult = manager.create(source);
        return Response.status(200)
                .entity(dbResult.getId().toString()).build();
}
```

**Serializer**

```
 public static String objectToString(Object object) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));

        Writer strWriter = new StringWriter();
        try {
            mapper.writeValue(strWriter, object);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        String userDataJSON = strWriter.toString();

        return userDataJSON;
    }
```

Can I set up my ObjectMapper to serialize all `null` as `""` or empty Object on my sending side?

If I pass a `UserContent` object with a `null` property to the above method, the resulting JSON will have `null` values like the example above and should the last item of a list have the value null, deserialization will abort causing NullPointerExceptions in my backend.

---

edit - the UserContent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_content")
@XmlRootElement
public class UserContent extends org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "content_post_id", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Contentcontent;

    // more properties...
}
```

our dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <jersey-version>1.14</jersey-version>
</properties>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You are missing the most important part of problem description, `UserContent` class. Please add it, so the problem can be either explained, or reproduced. Also, please include version of Jackson used.

Comment: Thanks StaxMan, didn't think that would be critical. Edited my post. Hope you might know what to do..

Comment: Any other Jackson modules in use? I also assume there must be getters or setters involved, since private fields are not otherwise detected. What I am getting as simply that of reproducing the problem. Similar structures are included in unit tests, so there should be something special about your use case; I am just trying to think of what might be the difference.

Comment: One more question: which Jackson version?

Comment: sorry, forgot those.. jackson 1.9.5

Comment: Oh ok. There was a bug in an earlier version, but that would have been 1.5 or 1.6. 1.9.5 should be new enough (although there are patches up to 1.9.11; but I don't remember any problems like this being fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution right now for this strange beahavior is to **ignore all null values on Serialization** by configuring the `ObjectMapper`:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

Which we can do as we controle both sides. I'm still curious about how to actually handle an incoming null value constelation as described above in case we make the REST service publicly available.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, and definitely should not break.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using jersey. You can try to replace jackson by [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/) on the server side, it should solve your problem. Indeed it looks like a bug. Be sure to remove jackson and jersey-json. You don't need any configuration to enable json support with Genson, just drop the jar in your classpath.